# Java: What should be done to use TreeBidiMap?

Tags: java

I want to use [this class](http://commons.apache.org/collections/api-release/org/apache/commons/collections/bidimap/TreeBidiMap.html).

Netbeans is rejecting the declaration:

```
import org.apache.commons.collections.bidimap.TreeBidiMap;
```

What should be done?

Comment: What do You mean exactly by rejection, could You provide the error message?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to put the commons collections jar into your classpath, so that Netbeans can find the classes inside.

Oh, and it needs to be the correct version (the doc looks like 3.0+ is required).